# Can you help me with this code error that I am getting while running the app?

Tags: android

It shows this error of **; expected** !! 
Where is the error? please guide me, I m new to it!
Dont know where its wrong...
Also it says **illegal start of expression**!

This may be stupid. But, i'm getting an error saying: "error: ';' expected  when trying to build the below code. I can't figure it out. Could anybody please help to sort out this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

```
package com.sv.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view;)
       {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You have a random `onClick` within your `onCreate` - that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You cant override onClick on nothing, you have to assign it to a view with a onClickListener

Remove this code

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view;)
   {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should looks more like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        (Button) findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
}
```

You can not Override methods in methods, also you have to find view to which you will want to perform some actions like in this example, I found button with id button and added to it listener